# Compound query returning whole database

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've been querying a friend request database but it's returning the whole table. The constraints are 2 parse users and a int. Is there a known bug, or is there an error in my code? I made the same query on android and it works fine.

```
           PFUser * unwanted = [self.allFriends objectAtIndex:2];
   self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];



NSLog(@"unwanted %@",unwanted);

PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"friendrequest"];
[query1 whereKey:@"user1" equalTo:self.currentUser];
[query1 whereKey:@"user2" equalTo:unwanted];
[query1 whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@3];
PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"friendrequest"];
[query1 whereKey:@"user1" equalTo:unwanted];
[query1 whereKey:@"user2" equalTo:self.currentUser];
[query1 whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@3];
PFQuery *query3 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"friendrequest"];
[query1 whereKey:@"user1" equalTo:self.currentUser];
[query1 whereKey:@"user2" equalTo:unwanted];
[query1 whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@1];
PFQuery *query4 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"friendrequest"];
[query1 whereKey:@"user1" equalTo:unwanted];
[query1 whereKey:@"user2" equalTo:self.currentUser];
[query1 whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@1];
PFQuery *finalQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query1,query2,query3,query4]];
[finalQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects,NSError *error){
    if(!error){
        NSLog(@"gotem %lu",(unsigned long)objects.count);
    }

}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BAD COPY/PASTER! Quit doing that. If you manually typed those, you'd have entered the correct query numbers rather than continually changing the settings for query1.  As you have it now, you have three queries for the friendRequest class that have no constraints whatsoever, and return every instance.

Comment: Hahaha thanks sometimes you just need another set of eyes, or just better coding skills.

Comment: Get in the habit of good programming practices as soon as you can, man. I'm currently kicking myself hard for lazy programming on a production app...